# How to undo a git checkout of a remote branch into a wrong local branch?

Tags: git

I had a local branch and a mapped remote branch, both of which were named `Foo`. That is, I had a local `Foo` and a remote `origin/Foo`.

There was also a remote branch named `origin/Bar` for which I didn't have any corresponding local.

I was in my branch `Foo` happily working when I wanted to take a peek at something inside branch `Bar`, so I foolishly did:

```
$ MINGW64 /me/local/path (Foo) git checkout Bar
```

which resulted in:

```
$ MINGW64 /me/local/path (Foo)
Checking out files: 100% done.
error: unable to write upstream branch configuration
hint:
hint: After fixing the error cause you may try to fix up
hint: the remote tracking information by invoking
hint: "git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/Bar".
```

The current branch indicator at the git bash prompt still reads `Foo` as below:

```
$ MINGW64 /me/local/path (Foo)
```

I am guessing that that merged the contents of the remote `Bar` into my nice local `Foo`, which is what I did *not* want to have happen.

I should have done

```
$ MINGW64 /me/local/path (Foo) git branch -b Bar origin/Bar
```

Or

```
$ MINGW64 /me/local/path (Foo) git branch Bar
$ MINGW64 /me/local/path (Foo) git checkout Bar
$ MINGW64 /me/local/path (Bar) git pull origin Bar
```

How do I undo what I did?

Comment: `git checkout Bar` does not merge `Bar` into `Foo`. It just switches the working tree from `Foo` to `Bar`. If you want to go back to `Foo`, simply run `git checkout Foo` or `git checkout -`.

Comment: can't you just delete branch `Bar`?

Comment: @ElpieKay The branch indicator at the git bash prompt that reads the current branch you're in still says I am in `Foo` which means I messed up and merged `origin/Bar` into my nice `Foo`. I want my `Foo` back.

Comment: Then you could have run some other commands. Run `git reflog Foo` to see how `Foo` changes. Find the right commit, run `git branch` and make sure you are now on `Foo`, and then run `git reset <commit> --hard`.

Comment: It's not clear quite what went wrong (probably running with wrong permissions, e.g., perhaps you created the entire repository as "administrator" and are now working as lowly "self" instead of "administrator"?—but this is Windows and I don't know Windows). But, when Git was unable to update the branch configuration, it should not have left you half-on half-off of the old branch `Foo`, e.g., should have taken you fully back *to* the old branch `Foo`. One thing it definitely did *not* do is merge anything, but it's not clear quite what it *did* do, when it was unable to finish.

Comment: @ElpieKay You saved me. I dug out `git reflog` and `git log` and then did a hard reset as you suggested. Thanks much.

Comment: @torek You're right. It did look like git left me in the lurch. I could see clearly that I was on branch `Foo` but the code in the solution was reloaded to reflect the code in branch `Bar`. I did a hard reset to an older commit on `Foo` and all the world is well again.

Comment: This certainly looks like a bug in Git; you might want to file it against the msysgit or mingw64 or whoever it is group (it may be Windows-specific, I've never seen this behavior on Unix-ish systems; if it can be reproduced on Unix, I'd leave it to the Windows people to come up with a Unix scenario). The hard reset is almost certainly the right workaround, but Git shouldn't be failing like this.

Comment: It's all right. Glad it helps.